# UIControllerView Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Clase Controller

```
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]


        // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

        // tell the collection view how many cells to make
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.items.count
        }

        // make a cell for each cell index path
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



            // get a reference to our storyboard cell
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellCollectionViewCell

            // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
            cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

            return cell
        }

        // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // handle tap events
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        }
```

Luego tengo esta clase con esta configuracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde dice Identifier le escribi "CellCollectionViewCell"

Tengo separado en clases [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al llegar a la linea de

```
 // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellCollectionViewCell
```

se cae , alguna ayuda con esto ? me parece que deberia ser sencillo , aunque no logro hacer que funcione , en el viewDidLoad tengo

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLabels()
    setupStyles()
    carosuel.delegate = self
    carosuel.dataSource = self 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontre mi problema , En el viewDidLoad metodo  me faltaba 1 linea

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLabels()
        setupStyles()

// ESTA LINEA QUE REGISTRA
         self.carosuel.register(UINib(nibName:"CellCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        carosuel.delegate = self
        carosuel.dataSource = self
    }
```